# How to remove double slashes (\\r\\n\\r\\n) in str_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to remove `<p>` and `</p>` from my JSON rest API output. I did the below but the output it gives me has double slashes like `\\r\\n\\r\\n`. So how do I change the double slashes to single?

Here's my code

```
//Remove <p> HTML element and replace with line breaks
$return = str_replace('<p>', '', $return);
$return = str_replace('</p>', '\r\n\r\n', $return);
        
//Output the data in JSON format without escaping the URL slashes
wp_send_json($return, 200, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Or can the above me more efficient if I use preg_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all is okay you Just need to use json_deocde in front side or where you want to print the result

Comment: Do you mean the receiving side will be able to decode it without an issue?

Comment: yes offcourse   from front_side string can be decoded

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does this automatically for security reasons. If you get the result on the user side ( frontend ), you can do this using JavaScript and the following code :

```
const result = response.data.replace(/\/\//g, "/");
```

Comment: They want to remove double **back**slashes!